# PHP with a MySQL master slaves (read replicas)

Tags: php, mysql

I’m trying to setup PHP (PDO) to use a MySQL setup with a single master and multiple slaves. I’ve scoured the Internet but am unable to find any real information.

1. Do I need to write any special code when connecting via PDO or is it transparent? So should I just connect to the master?
2. At some places I’ve read that the read replica is only meant as a backup ie it will replace the master in case of failure. I was under the impression that all read queries will be automatically redirected to the read replica. Is that true?

Comment: 1) If you want to connect to Master only and slave will be your backup, then you do not have to write any special code. If you want bot to work together, then yes, you have to write special code. Normally, if you are using specific frameworks like Drupal/Wordpress etc, you can download module/plugin. For custom code you have to write the logic on what you want. 2) Generally we use slave as backup, but can be used for all read queries also. You can see this drupal module for reference https://www.drupal.org/project/autoslave

Comment: Well we have that system with read redirects you've described in the second case, but we're using MariaDB MaxScale. I could explain you how it works if you're interested.